# Is every compact set rectifiable? example

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is every compact set rectifiable? The set is rectifiable iff it is compact and the boundary is of measure $0$ (This is stated as a theorem). Can I infer from this that every compact set is rectifiable?

**Edit** Definition of a rectifiable set: A set is rectifiable if the constant function $1$ is integrable over that set.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the definition of rectifiable ?'

Comment: I added it @learnmore

Comment: There are two definition of rectifiability stated. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: Where did you find this definition of rectifiable? What it actually is is a definition of "finite measure."

Comment: @MattSamuel I am studying from the Munkres, Analysis on Manifolds

Comment: @John Both of them are correct. At least the book says so

Comment: @Psycho You're talking about Riemann integration, right?

Comment: Obviously the set definitions are not the same. Take any bounded open set $U$. Then it is rectifiable in the second definition and it is not using the first definition (as it is not compact).

Comment: Right @user208259

Comment: I've got it: rectifiable = Jordan measurable with finite measure

Comment: @John I edited the post a little bit. Sorry for the mess

Comment: "I think according to the definition, the set is rectifiable iff it is compact and the boundary is of measure 0 (This is stated as a theorem)."

So which is it... definition or theorem?

Comment: More importantly....   What sort of measures are you using? Lebesgue?  Borel?  Positive? General?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my idea.  Take any set that you can perform a one-point compactification on it where the original set is not rectifiable, then the compactified set won't be either.

Example, take $\mathbb{N}$ with the modified counting measure (such that it is zero on the integer zero, i.e. $require$ that $\mu(0)=0$) then $\mu(\mathbb{N})=\infty$, and the one-point compactification of  $\mathbb{N}$ is $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}$ and the boundary $\{0\}$ has measure zero because we defined our measure this way. This is clearly compact and not rectifiable, because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty$.

Comment: Notice that under my modified counting measure that $\mu(\{0,1\}) = \mu(\{0\}\cup \{1\})=\mu(\{0\})+\mu(\{1\})=0+1$ NOT $2$.

Comment: So to answer your question.... the answer is no.

Comment: I'm not sure the question intends you to take an arbitrary measure.

Comment: Well....  The question was asked in pretty wide generality so I gave a general sort of answer.

Comment: @Squirtle: Actually, what is the definition of rectifiability?

Comment: @John... HA, great question!  There's this one (in the question) and about half a dozen others (see wikipedia)... in particular, I don't think I saw this one there.

Answer (score 4):

Construct a modified Cantor set as follows. Start with $A_0 = [0,1]$. Then take out the open  subinterval constituting the middle $1/4$. Let $A_1$ be the union of two intervals you have left. Then let $A_2$ be what you have left when you take out the middle $1/9$ of each of those intervals. And so on. Then let $A = \bigcap A_n$.

$A$ is compact with empty interior, so $A$ is its own boundary. However, its measure is $\prod_{n \geq 2} (1 - 1/n^2) > 0$. It might take a little work to show that it's not of measure zero without using measure theory.

Comment: "This might take a little work to show that it's not of measure zero without using measure theory."  Presumably they use measure theory if they know what measure zero means?

Comment: No, it's easy to define a set $S$ of measure zero. It means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, you can cover $S$ by a countable collection of intervals the sum of whose lengths is $< \varepsilon$